# Fastest way to set a dictionary value in python when greater than current key value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm running into the case often of having to set a dictionary key to a value (always an integer) if and only if the new value is greater than the old one. Profiling reveals the way I'm currently doing it is taking up a full 1/3 of the time of a certain function. Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
some_dict[k] = max(new_val, some_dict.get(k, 0))
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing the three different methods I can think of -

```
In [12]: def foo():
   ....:     d = {1:2 , 3:4}
   ....:     d[1] = max(3, d.get(1,0))
   ....:

In [13]: def foo1():
   ....:     d = {1:2, 3:4}
   ....:     if d.get(1,0) < 3:
   ....:         d[1] = 3
   ....:

In [14]: def foo2():
   ....:     d = {1:2, 3:4}
   ....:     d[1] = 3 if d.get(1,0) < 3 else d.get(1)
   ....:

In [15]: %timeit foo()
The slowest run took 4.18 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 µs per loop

In [16]: %timeit foo1()
The slowest run took 11.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 564 ns per loop

In [17]: %timeit foo2()
The slowest run took 4.79 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 556 ns per loop

In [18]: %timeit foo()
The slowest run took 10.17 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 861 ns per loop

In [19]: %timeit foo1()
The slowest run took 5.90 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 645 ns per loop

In [20]: %timeit foo2()
The slowest run took 8.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 523 ns per loop
```

If we were to believe `%timeit`'s result seems like doing the following is fastest -

```
some_dict[k] = new_val if some_dict.get(k, 0) < new_val else some_dict.get(k)
```

This assumes that new_val would always be greater than 0, and hence we do not need `some_dict.get(k,0)` in the else part. Though even with that there is not much difference.

Comment: My experiment yields the same result, tenary operator is the fastest. I also tried a subclass of dict with `__setitem__()` overrided, it doesn't beat the tenary operator in speed.

Comment: Marking this correct, unless someone comes up with something faster.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious other way is to not always do the assignment, and not invoke an extra function call:

```
if some_dict.get(k, 0) < new_val:
    some_dict[k] = new_val
```

Whether or not that's actually faster is another question.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method not mentioned yet:

```
get = d.get
val = get(k, 0)
d[k] = (val, new_val)[val<new_val]
```

This method plays only with memory, not using branches at all.

How fast is it? Hm, it should be pretty fast.

```
get = d.get
```

Saves the pointer outside the dictionary for faster access to the method.

You may play around with dict.setdefault() as well.
It is a funny little method.

See help(dict.setdefault).

Comment: Not sure why but when i ran it with timeit, this method was a bit slower than `some_dict[k] = new_val if some_dict.get(k, 0) < new_val else some_dict.get(k)` . Maybe because my dictionary is short . Could you please update if you have some timing info

Comment: Odd, it consists of few steps:

Getting value out of d[k] or returning 0; Forming a tuple(val, new_val); evaluating val&lt;new_val; indexing the tuple; asigning to d[k].

Now, we can see whether forming lists is faster than forming tuples: [val, new_val][val<new_val]  Or, perhaps hashing for a dict() takes speed while branching removes unnecessary asignment.

Comment: I used this method on a growing dict which will contain thousands of entries on end with strings as keys. Each of them could be very long.
It was a duplicate line removing algorithm for removing headers and footers out of eBooks.
This worked unbelievably fast. I never did time tests so I don't know how fast it really is.
You can create yourself a big dict easily: some_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(10**7), 15)  All values will be 15, but who cares. It'll give you i.e. us more precise timeit results.

Comment: I tried the same on the `dict` you proposed (tests similar to what i did in mine) and this method took 0.9 secs more than the one in my answer - `In [44]: %timeit foo3()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop

In [45]: %timeit foo2()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.06 s per loop`

Comment: As for what it is so, I have no idea. I may only speculate that Python has some very good optimization method for branches and that hashing and assigning to a dict isn't extra fast. Anyway, indexing a list or tuple with a boolean obtained using conditions is still cool. :D And taking a reference of a method out of object should speed things up. This trick you may use in your solution to improve it. Well if it does speed things up. Now I am not certain of anything any more. :D

Comment: That being said I like your answer :) , didn't know you could do that :)

Comment: @Anand   You would be surprised what is possible in Python. Give it the proper hardware, type few lines of code and it will fly if you want it to. I saw one-liner Python implementation of quick sort. I was shocked for days.